# How to delete excess rows in Excel

Tags: excel, powershell

I'm trying to clean up my data. I have seen a number of treads about this topic. I've followed and applied the examples but something seems wrong with my script.

[image: Screenshot of a sample Excel file I was trying to clean up]

What I wanted to do is to delete the entire row when the no. column is null. When I run my script only half of the rows with null no. column are deleted. I would have to run my script multiple times before all the null rows are fully deleted. Is there a limit in deleting rows in PowerShell or I am missing something? Here's my script:

```
#cleanup
$max = $sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

for ($i = 6; $i -le $max; $i++) {
    if ($sheet.Cells.Item($i, 1).Text -eq "") {
        $Range = $sheet.Cells.Item($i, 1).EntireRow
        $Range.Delete()
    }
}
```

**UPDATES:** 
To address the deleting problem I added $i = $i - 1.. now I have to find a way to stop the loop

```
 for ($i = 6; $i -le $row; $i++) {
    If ($Sheet.Cells.Item($i, 1).text -eq "") {
        $Range = $Sheet.Cells.Item($i, 1).EntireRow
        [void]$Range.Delete()
        $i = $i - 1
    } 
}
```

Comment: Are the cells maybe populated with a blank space hence the if condition not satisfied ?

Comment: The condition is actually satified. What's weird is that if I run the script for the second time it would delete half of the rows with null no. column. On the third run it would again delete half.. so on until all the null rows are deleted.

Comment: @MichelleSantos Not too familiar with PS, but in Excel VBA, if deleting rows, you need to work from the bottom up, else the pointer to the row gets confused as rows get deleted.  If that is the same in PS, perhaps all you need to do is reverse  direction

Comment: @RonRosenfeld It's not that the pointer gets confused, but if you're deleting rows in a `for` loop you'll be skipping a row every time you delete a row. If row n is deleted, the former row n+1 now becomes row n. However, since the index is automaticall incremented, you're going to the *new* row n+1 (former row n+2) in the next iteration, thus skipping the *former* row n+1 (new row n). You avoid this effect by going back to front.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Thanks for the more detailed explanation of what I described as "confused".  Trying to delete top-to-bottom is a frequent mistake made in the Excel-VBA forums.  And, of course, in doing so, the row pointer is not pointing to the row expected by the programmer,  for the reasons you outlined.

Comment: Thanks for the insight guys.. @RonRosenfeld that was actually the cause of the problem.. I added $i = $i - 1 to address the problem and everything worked fine on the delete part but I am currently trapped on a loop..

Comment: @MichelleSantos Again, not familiar with PS, but can't you loop from `$max to 6`, instructing PS to decrement i each time?  In VBA you would write something like `for i = max to 6 step -1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're deleting rows in a "forward" `for` loop you'll be skipping a row every time you delete a row. If row n is deleted, the former row n+1 now becomes row n. However, since the index is automatically incremented, you're going to the new row n+1 (former row n+2) in the next iteration, thus skipping the former row n+1 (new row n).

**Example:**

Consider having a table like this (first column are the row numbers):

```
  ┌──────────
1 │ A
  ├──────────
2 │ B
  ├──────────
3 │ C
  ├──────────
```

and a `for` loop like this:

```
for ($i=1; $i -le 2; $i++) {
  $sheet.Rows.Item($i).Delete()
}
```

In the first iteration `$i` has the value 1, so it points to row 1:

```
  ┏━━━━━━━━━━
1 ┃ A
  ┡━━━━━━━━━━
2 │ B
  ├──────────
3 │ C
  ├──────────
```

By deleting that row, the subsequent rows are moved up, so table becomes like this (at the end of the first iteration):

```
  ┌──────────
1 │ B
  ├──────────
2 │ C
  ├──────────
```

The second row has now become the first row. However, when going into the next iteration, the variable `$i` is incremented to 2, so it now points to row 2 (the former third row):

```
  ┌──────────
1 │ B           ← skipped this row
  ┢━━━━━━━━━━
2 ┃ C
  ┡━━━━━━━━━━
```

You avoid this effect by going back to front, starting at the bottom row:

```
$max = $sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
for ($i = $max; $i -ge 6; $i--) {
    if ($sheet.Cells.Item($i, 1).Text -eq '') {
        $Range = $sheet.Rows.Item($i).Delete()
    }
}
```

Beware that `.UsedRange.Rows.Count` will not necessarily give you the number of the last row. If you have empty rows before the first used row you need to add their number as an offset to the number of rows in the used range:

```
$max = $sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + $sheet.UsedRange.Row - 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the complete explanation @Ansgar I was able to solve the problem using the backward loop but I added just a little something.. I'll post my answer but I found your comment very useful..

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem above I made use of a backward for loop instead of a forward for loop.. thank you @RonRosenfeld for the idea.. @AnsgarWiechers gave a very insightful explanation of why it is inappropriate to use a forward loop. His answer just needs a little adjustment. Setting $i -ge 6 is still not a guaranteed end point for the backward loop. To stop the loop I added a else statement that when the $Sheet.Cells.Item($i, 1).text is no longer equal to "null" it would set $i = 0. This would end the backward loop.

```
 #cleanup
$max = $sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count


for ($i = $max; $i -ge 0; $i--) {
    If ($Sheet.Cells.Item($i, 1).text -eq "") {
        $Range = $Sheet.Cells.Item($i, 1).EntireRow
        [void]$Range.Delete()
        echo $i
    } 
    Else {$i = 0}
}
```

Comment: Collections in MS Office applications are 1-based, not 0-based, so your stop condition should be `$i -gt 0` or `$i -ge 1`. That way you won't need the `else` branch. Whenever you're manually changing the index variable inside a `for` loop there's a good chance you're doing something wrong.

Comment: but given that the rows 1 to 10 are not null the backward loop wont end because $i would never be equal to 0 or 1. The loop wont stop unless a condition is specified.

Comment: What gave you that idea? The counter is decremented regardless of whether the first cell in the row is empty or not.

Comment: You are actually correct. I've tested it. I would keep that noted @AnsgarWiechers